# Простая программа/скрипт(bash)

Tags: linux, bash

Посчитайте, в какое количестве подкаталогов каталога, имя которого указано в параметре командной строки, вы имеете право войти. Указание: наличие права можно проверить путем перехода в этот каталог и проверки успеха операции.

```
echo $(ls -l $(read)| grep ^d| wc -l)
```

пока что дошёл до такого, но это собственно не верно, возможно можно из

```
echo $(ls -l $(read)|grep ^d)
```

сделать переменную и попытаться открыть каждую директорию циклом, каждый раз прибавлять 1 в случае удачи.

Не знаю, как правильно написать кодом

Comment: в такой редакции вопрос однозначно подлежит закрытию. во-первых, как учебное задание, во-вторых, как слишком общий. задавайте каждый вопрос, на который не знаете ответ, по отдельности (кнопка «задать вопрос» в правом верхнем углу). примерно: 1. как получить список каталогов. 2. как изменить текущий каталог. 3. как проверить, удачно ли выполнилась предыдущая команда. 4. как добавить единицу к числу, хранящемуся в переменной. и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: Тогда вопрос следующий, как из echo $(ls -l $(read)|grep ^d) 
получить массив прав, то есть получить массив ['drwxrwxr-x', 'd---rwxr-x']

Comment: Для начала начните со штудирование *man find*. Вопрос надо просто удалить.

Comment: @0andriy find exec?

Answer (score -1):

Простое решение

```
echo $(ls -l $(read)| grep ^dr| wc -l)
```

Comment: Первый 'r' это право чтения каталога для владельца. Вы можете не быть владельцем этого каталога и данная r на вас не распространится. Кроме того, отсутствие права 'x' не позволит вам войти в каталог. Так что стоит прислушаться к тому, что собственно было предложено в тексте задачи: попробовать войти в каждый каталог и посмотреть чем это закончится. Так что все таки find пройтись по каталогам и для каждого выполнить что то вроде `cd {} 2>/dev/null && echo 1 && cd ..` (где `{}` стандартный подставляемый параметр find). После чего уже посчитать полученные единицы